# Why does text modified by jQuery look lighter on hover in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I haven't asked this earlier because it's difficult to explain, but when I have jQuery interacting with text elements, when the mouse is hovered on them, the font shows up noticeably thinner/lighter.

For example, I have a main navigation menu on my page. jQuery interacts with it as the window is scrolled to keep it visible. If I am scrolled all the way up on the page (jQuery has not interacted with the menu), I can hover over each link and nothing changes. However, if I scroll down to where jQuery adds classes,etc. to the nav menu, when I hover over a link the text appears much thinner.

This does not happen in other browsers that I've noticed (at least not in FireFox for sure), but only Safari.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing any code, maybe jQuery is changing the `class` of the element. The new CSS class might have different font styles - family, weight or size

Comment: No, it's not that at all. Nothing of the font styles are changing which is confirmed in other browsers. Only Safari has this issue.

Comment: I think adding proper library with proper integration will work in all browsers. Some of the features are deprecated in the libraries that's why you are facing this issues

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Without showing us any of your code, I don't know what we can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a { -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; }
```

That will fix it.